# How do I update git to its latest version on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I have git version 1.7.4.1. and would like to upgrade to the latest stable release of 1.8.4.

So I tried `sudo apt-get install git` as it says on the [git downloads page for Linux](http://git-scm.com/download/linux) but I get this result:

```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  git is already the newest version.
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.

$ git --version 
  git version 1.7.4.1
```

and I'm stuck with git version 1.7.4.1!

I am on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: What distro and version are you running?

Comment: It looks like that version has been end-of-lifed and thus not getting updates, but askubuntu.com likely could give you a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to Ubuntu has not updated the package yet in their repositories. The only way around this would be to compile from source, which you can download from https://github.com/git/git.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you elaborate on it? So once I download the latest git, by for example `git clone https://github.com/git/git`, what should I do to have it installed?

Comment: Ah, I found it, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL :)

Comment: usually all you have to do is ./configure && make && sudo make install

Comment: And install the utilities necessary to run those commands... `build-essential` is usually all you need.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y --> 
sudo apt-get update --> 
sudo apt-get install git -->
git --version

Answer (score 2):

There are Ubuntu PPAs for Git, offering the latest version of it. Add one of those and you'll be able to install it. For example:

https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa

Read the "Adding this PPA to your system" information on how to do this.

Comment: There is no package for 11.04 natty in that PPA, so it is of no use to the OP.

Comment: @NevikRehnel Then I guess he needs to look for another PPA. I'm not doing the searching for him. I just mentioned that there are PPAs out there.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your whole system to raring at least:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git-core

(If you adhere to packaged version.)

But the source will be more fresh anyway.